# Reusing Persistent Volume for another PersistentVolumeClaim

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I am using rookio on Kubernetes with CoreOS for dynamically creating Persistent Volume.

So I create a PersistentVolumeClaim (`kubectl create -f postgres-pvc.yaml`) and apply a patch for persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy to Retain.  I do a `"kubectl get pv"`and I can see a dynamically created persistentvolume and is bound.  Now when I delete the PersitentVolumeClaim the status goes to Released.

I have stored some precious data in that persistentvolume.  Is there a way I can reuse that persistentvolume that has gone into Released status?

thanks
-sonam

Answer (score 2):

If you have precious data that you want to use in another PostgreSQL pod, maybe StatefulSets is which you are looking for, as it allows:

> Stable, persistent storage [...] across Pod (re)schedulings.

Therefore, I would advise you to deploy your PostgreSQL database as a StatefulSet. You would need to check that your already existing Volume is bound.

---

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I read about stateful sets but I don't see a whole lot of difference between a regular pod and a stateful pod in regards to reusing the pv if the pvc is deleted.